# How to find the number of workers used by a Google Data flow SDK pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a dataflow job and it is getting executed in cloud. I can see the job is being executed and the steps being executed

But where can I find the number of workers used for my job?

This is just to find out what will be the cost of my job running in google dataflow.

Answer (score 1):

On the Developers Console, navigate to Compute > Compute Engine > VM instances.  This will bring up a list of VMs your project has running.

Comment: That shows me the CPU utilization, N/W utilization and disk utilization. But it does not show me the number of VM instances used.

Comment: Is there any other place where can I look for the number of workers used for my dataflow job?

Answer (score 0):

You can visualize it in Dataflow/Monitoring tab

[image]